# How to show an error message when no data is found while filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, error-handling, filtering

I have a component, where I am doing search filtering & dropdown filtering, filtering is working but I am not able to figure it out where to show error if there is no data found while filtering. Can anyone help me with this

```
 searchSpace = (event) => {
            this.setState({
              search: event.target.value,
            });
          };
    
 sortOptions = [
    {value: "ALL", label: "All"},
    { value: "Iphone", label: "Iphone" },
    { value: "Samsung", label: "Samsung" },
  ];

  getSelectedItem = (items, selectedValue) => {
    return items.find((item) => item.value === selectedValue);
  };

  dropdown = (event) => {
        console.log("filter", event.selectedItem.value);
        this.setState({
          filter: event.selectedItem.value,
        });
      };

     render() {
           const { details} = this.state;
          const items = this.state.details
              .filter((data) => {
                if (this.state.search == null) return data;
                else if (data.includes(this.state.search)) {
                  return data;
                }                
              })
              const data = items
              .filter((data) => this.state.filter === "" || data === this.state.filter)
              .map((data) =>
                   <>
                  <ShareCard></ShareCard>
                </>    
            );
    return (
  <Search placeHolderText="Search" onChange={(e) => this.searchSpace(e)}/>

<Dropdown id="filtering items={this.sortOptions}
 onChange={(e) => this.dropdown(e)}
  selectedItem={this.getSelectedItem(
 this.sortOptions,
 this.state.filter
 )} />

    <div>{data}</div>
    )
    );
```

Comment: Are you asking where, in your JSX, to display some error messaging if `items` is an empty array?

Comment: Right, i am not sure where to put boolean or something, to show error message when items is empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple use-case to display an error if `items` is empty is to use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). If the `items` array length is truthy, i.e. greater than zero, then render the data, otherwise render error message.

```
<div>
  {items.length ? data : "Error: There are no items!!"}
</div>
```